# SQL: Find value in Column A and update Column B with another value

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a few columns. Some of the values gets populated in the database but not all.

I want to search a value in one column and update another column with a certain value.

My TABLE (name = "heroes") looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id |  name  | last_name | hero_id | status |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | John   | Snow      | 3245625 |        |
| 2  | Tyrion | Lannister | 7687296 | Alive  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I want to search the database for the 'hero_id' (which is unique) and UPDATE the 'status' column.

The search part I can do:

```
SELECT idnumber, status FROM heroes WHERE idnumber=3245625
```

How do I go about updating the "status" column with a certain value e.g. "Alive" or "Deceased"?

Comment: You've tagged `sql-server` and `mysql` here. Please update your tags for the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: so, are you using mysql or SQL Server?, please use the relevant tags only

Comment: `update heroes set status = 'whatever' where hero_id = 3245625`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H,
try this one:

```
UPDATE heroes
SET STATUS = "Alive"
WHERE idnumber=3245625;
```

Cheers
Para

Answer (score 0):

```
update heroes set status = 'alive' where id = 12354
```